# How do I get to work my Atheros AR9485 Wireless card in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, drivers, atheros

I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my **ASUS D550CA**, and so far things have gone great.

The only problem I've got is the Wi-Fi. *It doesn't work*.

I've got an **Qualcomm Atheros AR9485**. I've tried installing the drivers, but the sytem says it doesn't find any.

So I started looking around this forum for solutions.

I've read every single post from this forum about my Wi-Fi network adapter, and I've found nothing that solves my problem.

Let me give you some info about my configuration.

**Disclaimer**: my configuration is in spanish, so if you don't understand something you can either use Google translate, or use your imagination. :D

When I run `$ sudo lshw -C network` this is what I get:

```
*-network DEACTIVATED   
   descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
   producto: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
   fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   nombre lógico: wlan0
   versión: 01
   serie: 28:e3:47:5c:5d:3f
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuración: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.13.0-34-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   recursos: irq:17 memoria:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memoria:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
  *-network
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0.2
       información del bus: pci@0000:03:00.2
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 06
       serie: e0:3f:49:ce:57:49
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8402-1_0.0.1 10/26/11 ip=181.165.245.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:f0004000-f0004fff memoria:f0000000-f0003fff
```

At the beginning, you'll see that it says "*-network DEACTIVATED" (or at least that's what I translated), is that something bad?

Then, when I run `ipconfig` this is what I get:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW e0:3f:49:ce:57:49  
          Direc. inet:181.165.245.39  Difus.:181.165.245.255  Másc:255.255.255.0
          Dirección inet6: fe80::e23f:49ff:fece:5749/64 Alcance:Enlace
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÓN FUNCIONANDO MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:221199 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:62025 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:124409589 (124.4 MB)  TX bytes:7471899 (7.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  Másc:255.0.0.0
          Dirección inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:Anfitrión
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  Métrica:1
          Paquetes RX:2977 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:2977 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:0 
          Bytes RX:397158 (397.1 KB)  TX bytes:397158 (397.1 KB)
```

When I put `iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Finally, when I put `sudo rfkill list all`, I got:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I hope anyone can help me solve this, I've searched a lot and **found no solution**.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wireless is blocked by the wireless switch or key combination; please see:

> Hard blocked: yes

Please try the key combination, Fn+F2 or similar and run again:

```
rfkill list all
```

Any change? If not, is the module *asus_nb_wmi* loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

Reboot and see if your wireless key combination is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Encountered the same problem today on a headless Ubuntu 12.04 server with PCI Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 wlan. I believe that unblocking with rfkill should solve it.

```
rfkill unblock all
```

However, I could not even get Internet access to install `rfkill`. So, while installing Ubuntu 14 server on the same machine, I chose the `Qualcomm Atheros AR9485` as the primary `NIC` and it connected to a wireless router during configuration. If its still disabled after you complete installation, you may have to include it in network interfaces

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

then append

```
auto wlan0
.....
```

Remember to include the `essid`(case sensitive), IP,and wep/wap security (google that)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** And sorry to say, but "Google that" is not an answer.  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...