# Ubuntu 16.04 - cannot re-connect the WiFi network after connection changes

Tags: networking, 16.04, hardware, nic

Say my Ubuntu laptop connected to a WiFi network. For some reason I had to restart my wireless router. After the router rebooted successfully, the WiFi network list will not update itself and only when I log out and in system again, the network can be set up automatically. Same thing will happen when I turn off the network function on Ubuntu and try to reconnect.
This always does. Any one can help?

The system is x64_86 and run on my ASUS - K550L laptop. I think the problem arose from when I installed the system ( I cleared all my disk for Ubuntu :) ) It's not that unacceptable but really annoying me sometimes.. Any help would be appreciated!

After Running

> lspci -nn

Gives the following information:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0a03] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:9c18] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal [8086:9c24] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Hi Hao, we need more information about your hardware, like what laptop model it is and what type of wireless device you are using (run lspci -nn in the terminal)

Comment: Could you take a look at the answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/514018/how-do-i-get-to-work-my-atheros-ar9485-wireless-card-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts and let me know if that solves your issue. The user chili555 is an expert on the subject.